# How to get the request URL relative to the application root?

Tags: yii

If I do this:

```
print Yii::app()->request->url;
```

I get:

```
/www/site/contact
```

on my local machine. But on my site I get:

```
/site/contact
```

How can I get the path from where index.php is located, so that on both local and my server I end up with:

```
/site/contact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip the [`baseUrl`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#baseUrl-detail) you can get with `Yii::app()->baseUrl` out from the request url.

One way to do that is:

```
$app = Yii::app();
print substr($app->request->url, strlen($app->baseUrl));
```